# Why are parens used in Qt reinterpret_cast< int(*)>

Tags: qt

Here an example of Qt generated by moc code:

```
case 0: valueChanged((*reinterpret_cast< int(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
```

Why is it `int(*)` but not `int*`?

```
case 0: valueChanged((*reinterpret_cast< int*>(_a[1]))); break;
```

Answer (score 3):

Both are equivalent. Presumably, including redundant parentheses in some places makes the code generation logic simpler and more reliable; but you wouldn't do that if you were writing the code yourself.